# What happens when two conflicting laws both say "notwithstanding any other provision of law..."?

Tags: statutory-construction

What happens when two conflicting laws both say "notwithstanding any other provision of law..."?

Notwithstanding any other provision of law, you shall pay me all of your money.

Notwithstanding any other provision of law, you shall pay John all of your money.

Comment: Which one was passed more recently?

Comment: Well, let's say the John one had the most recent "revision"

Answer (score 3):

The latter law repeals the former law by implication.

Comment: This could do with additional explanation.

Comment: @Nij The term of art "notwithstanding" is the legislature recognizing that the new law contains terms that have a contrary purpose from the original intent of the terms, as applied, to "any other provision of law" that is still in effect. Depending on the construction the original intent could control, or the legislature repeals by implication the old law when not repealed expressly if a contrary or absurd interpretation of the new law is reached when applied to a term having an existing clearly defined legal meaning if the new law uses the term for a different purpose the new intent controls.